# Debugging C forked process stopping on fork

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, netbeans, fork

I have to debug some forked process.
I'd like to debug both parent and child processes.

As in other question, i activate both "Non-stop mode" and "Automatically debug forked process".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CilxY.png)
Here born the problem:
now when I reach the fork instruction everything stops and i don't know how to continue.
Here the simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int pid=fork();
    if (pid>0)
    {
        printf("FATHER PROCESS");
    } else if(pid<0)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        exit(1);
    } else
    {
        printf("I'M THE CHILD PROCESS");
        exit(2);
    }
    printf("\nEND");
    return 0;
}
```

The child process starts, but i don't know what can i do now.
I tried in eclipse and in NetBeans, but they have the same problem.
When i use the debugger console, typing 'n' this is the output:

> [New process 3077]
> Reading symbols from /home/user/programmi/eclipse-workspace/provaFork/Debug/provaFork...done.
>
> Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so...done.
>
> Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so...done.
>
> Warning:
>
> Cannot insert breakpoint 11.
>
> Cannot access memory at address 0x6d2
>
> Cannot insert breakpoint 10.
>
> Cannot access memory at address 0x6e0
>
> Cannot insert breakpoint 7.
>
> Cannot access memory at address 0x714
>
>
> Command aborted.
>
> (gdb) [Switching to thread 2.2 (process 3077)]
>
> #0  0x00007ffff7ac8b1c in ?? ()

The process 3077 is the child process (i think).
If i type 'n' another time i get:

> Cannot find bounds of the current function

If i disable "Automatically debug forked process" the process continues, but i can't debug the child process.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do so many users insist on putting newline chars at the start of strings?

Comment: It's my error sorry, now i'll edit.

Comment: [Sigh]… it's usual to put newlines at the end of output strings.

Comment: I think this is a question of personal preference.

Comment: I don't think it's so important matter now...
But if you say "why do so many..." it's not so usual to put at the end as you are saying (but if there is a reason to prefer '\n' at the end i'm curious).

Comment: If there is no newline at the end, I/O line buffering causes flow-control confusion, especially with some operations, e.g. fork().

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know. Thank you.